# Determine the Dimension of Given subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Subspace $$W=\{(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_{10}) : x_n=x_{n-1}+x_{n-2},3\le n\le 10\}$$

$$\dim W=?$$

I Just figure out a vector of $W$ and trying to generate that vector by standard basis, If $x_1=1,x_2=2,$ then $x_3=3,x_4=5,x_5=7,x_6=12,x_7=19,x_8=31,x_9=50,x_{10}=81$

So, the vector will be $X=(1,2,3,5,7,12,19,31,50,81)$

To generate this vector by standard basis we need $10$ basis elements, so $\dim W=10$. But I don't think this works.

Any Help is Appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Answer will be $2$..

Comment: (Only a) hint - set $x_1 = 1$, and $x_2 = 0.$ Then set $x_1 =0$, and $x_2 = 1$. This gives you 2 vectors. Can you write your $X$ in terms of these vectors?

Comment: Downvoter, can you explain the reason of downvoting? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dimension is 2. Write $W$ as:
$$W = \{(a,b,a+b,a+2b,2a+3b,\ldots,13a+21b,21a+34a) \mid a,b \in \mathbb R\}.$$
Choose $a = 1,b=0$ and $a = 0,b=1$ to make two linearly independent vectors. Since $x_3,\ldots,x_{10}$ are uniquely determined by the first two elements, the vectors also span $W$.

Answer (score 2):

Answer will be $2$..

Because from $x_3$ to $x_{10}$ all can be written as a linear combination of $x_1$ and $x_2$

Comment: Thanx, Suppose this question comes in exam, what argument should I write.

Comment: on an exam, use the hint from  peter a g

Comment: @ Chiranjeev) Follow 'Nitin's ' answer..

Comment: @Chiranjeev I totally agree!